# How to change the report's "document map" root label?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005, .net-3.5, reportviewer

*Technologies: .net 3.5, Visual Studio 2010, Report Viewer Control version 10, c#*

I am using adhoc reports in my winform application, now here is the problem:

When my report is rendered in the viewer, the document map displays the report file name as the the root node of the document map. I need to display a more user-friendly description.

How can the document map's root be changed?

tnx. :)

Comment: wow... almost a year and no answer(s)...

Comment: How do you add a document map to a report in VS2010 in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be done in the code:

```
LocalReport.DisplayName="User-friendly name.";
```

Answer (score 0):

[Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the label for the root node in the document map.  It is always set to the name of the report. MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/d33bad8f-ab34-4520-835e-70472c4d3ce0/)